# Why is it not possible to have an IF statement in a TRY block in Python, and if somehow possible, is it good practice?

Tags: python, exception

I am getting an indentation error, but my code is indented properly.  If I take out the if statement, the code will run fine.  Here is the relevant snippet:

```
 80     try:
 81         votes_a = breakdown[0]['count']
 82
 83         if breakdown[0]['pick'] != m.home:
 84            votes_b = votes_a
 85     except IndexError:
 86         votes_a = 0.0
```

If I remove lines 83 and 84 the code will work.  Is it not possible/advisable to have control statements within try/except blocks of python code?

cheers

Update:
The indentation error was not in the line that django told me, it was the line above.  And, yes, there was one tab thrown in there instead of a space.  Thanks.

Comment: what's the error you get with line 83 and  84.? it is perfectly okay to have  control statements within try/except blocks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course it's possible. If you get indentation errors, but indentation looks good visually, there's a good chance you've mixed tabs with spaces. It's best to not use tabs at all. You can run Python with `-tt` to detect inconsistent tab usage.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Tabs mixed with spaces was my first thought.  I have ensured that there are only spaces.

Comment: @ChrisD. Then please show the *exact* error message you get from your Python interpreter. All we know now is that you get "an indentation error".

Comment: Wait, now you've accepted this answer... Did you have any tabs in the file? Does your code work now? What was the resolution?

Answer (score 3):

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> breakdown = []
>>> breakdown.append({'count':5, 'pick':0})
>>> abc = 0
>>> try:
...     votes_a = breakdown[0]['count']
...     if breakdown[0]['pick'] != abc:
...             votes_b = votes_a
... except IndexError:
...     votes_a = 0.0
...
>>> print votes_a
5
>>>
```

As it seems, the code itself is fine. You must've messed up spaces/tabs somewhere